# Rational integer belongs to at most certain number of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose that $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. How can one go about proving that a non-zero rational number $q$ belongs to at most $q^{n}$ ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$?

Would you be so kind as to provide me with a hint for this exercise? How can I link the decomposition of $q$ as product of irreducible elements of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ with the decomposition of $\langle q \rangle$ as a product of prime ideals? Does it help at all?

Thanks for leaving your suggestions.

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Likely the degree of the extension.

Comment: That's right!......

Comment: Ah OK! The point is that if $\mathfrak p$ is a maximal ideal, then $q\in \mathfrak p$ if and only if $\mathfrak p\mid\langle q\rangle$ as ideals.

Comment: @Mathmo123: Would you be so kind as to elaborate?

Comment: @Jamai-Con if $q$ itself is prime, then $\langle q\rangle$ splits into at most $n$ ideals, so $q$ is contained in at most $n$ ideals. The general case follows by multiplying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Mathmo's comment, decompose $n$ into its prime factors in $\mathbb Z $  $$n=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{r_i} $$ and you know that each prime splits in $O_K$ as $$p_iO_K = \prod_{j=1}^{g_i} \mathfrak p_{ij}^{e_{ij}} $$
such all the $\mathfrak p_{ij}$ are distinct and that $\sum_{j=1}^{g_i} e_{ij}f_{ij}\leq n$ where $f_{ij}$ are the respective inertial degrees. We can ignore them to get a coarse bound $\sum_{j=1}^{g_i} e_{ij}\leq n$. So the ideal generated by $n$ in $O_K$ is $$nO_K=\prod_{i,j}\mathfrak p_{ij}^{r_ie_{ij}} $$

Now for $n$ to be contained in an ideal $I$, it needs to be $$I=\prod_{i,j}\mathfrak p_{ij}^{a_{ij}} $$ 
with the non-negative integers $0\leq a_{ij}\leq r_ie_{ij}$. So we are down to showing that $$\prod_{i=1}^k\prod_{j=1}^{g_i} (r_ie_{ij}+1) \leq q^n.$$ I don't feel like combinatorics rn, so can you help me finish?

Answer (score 6):

Actually it is easier to find the answer with the correct level of generality: take $q\in \mathcal{O}_K$ and replace $q^n$ with the norm $|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(q)|$.

The ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ that contain $q$ are in bijection with the ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K/q\mathcal{O}_K$. Moreover, every ideal of $R = \mathcal{O}_K/q\mathcal{O}_K$ is principal. Now count how many principal ideals there can be in $R$.

Comment: This is lovely, especially compared to my chainsaw approach to the problem! +1

Comment: @Aurel: How do you know that $\mathcal{O}_{K}/ \langle q \rangle$ is a PID?

Comment: @Jamai-Con It is not a PID, because it is (in general) not a domain. But it is a PIR: every ideal is principal. This is very classical, but let me give a proof. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, which we lift to $J$ an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ containing $q$. By the CRT, there exists $x\in\mathcal{O}_K$ having same valuations as $J$ at the prime ideals dividing $q$ (and possibly other nontrivial valuations at other primes). Then $J = x\mathcal{O}_K + q\mathcal{O}_K$ by comparing prime factorisations, i.e. $I = xR$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if there is a valuation-free proof of the "principality" of this ring?

Comment: I don't think so, because (if I remember correctly) there is a structure theorem for finite (or even Artinian) PIR that tells you that they are products of PIR with a valuation-like structure (maybe even quotients of DVRs, I cannot remember the precise statement).