# Rational Integer contained in finite number of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

My question is about the proof for Rings of Integers of Number Fields of the following statement:

> (a) Any non-zero ideal has a finite number of divisors 
> (b) Any non-zero rational integer is contained in a finite number of ideals.

Which goes as follows (Tall, David Orme Stewart, Ian - Algebraic number theory and Fermat’s last theorem-Peters (2002)) :

> **Proof**: (a) is an immediate consequence of prime factorization, (b) is a
> special case of (a).

But to me, (b) isn't as easy to see. Are "my" reasonings correct?

**Proof:**

(b) Let $n$ be a rational integer. The Ideals such that $I|\langle n \rangle$ are in bijection with those of $R:=\mathfrak{O}/p\mathfrak{O}$ and $|R|$ is the Norm of the ideal $\langle n \rangle$, which is finite. It makes sense to me that a finite Ring can only contains finitely many Ideals, which proves our statement. (I would prove the last statement by considering $\langle X \rangle$, for $\emptyset \neq X \subset R$ and showing that any ideal in $R$ is expressible in that way and since $X$ is in $2^R$ and $|2^R|$ is finite, we are done).

(a) I don't have an issue with the book here, but here goes "my" proof just in case: There is a unique up to factors decomposition into prime ideals for some Ideal $I$ and any Ideal contained in $I' \subset I$ is also constructed by combinations of these prime ideals, there are only finitely many such combinations (since we consider products of finitely many prime ideals) and thus we are done.

I am aware that this is related to:
[Rational integer belongs to at most certain number of ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496806/rational-integer-belongs-to-at-most-certain-number-of-ideals)

Comment: Don't use $p$ for non-primes :-) Yes $O/(a)$ is a finite ring automatically implies that it has finitely many ideals so there are finitely many ideals of $O$ containing $a$.

Comment: Thank you! I have now replaced $p$ with $n$.